# How to add custom views or overide views for Django Admin index?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

urls.py ->

```
 ''''from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from Administrator import views

    admin.site.index_template = 'admin/dashboard.html'
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
           ]
```

'''

I have added a custom `admin_index` template in `urls.py`. My doubt is shown in the picture.

My Admin index custom `template.Kindly`:

[image: My Admin index custom template.Kindly, See it]

Comment: I am trying to override admin index page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can override the `AdminSite`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) and then in this custom admin site class you can override the `index` method to provide additional context that you can then use in your template

```
class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['foo'] = 'bar'
        return super().index(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this,  the code below should work.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls , {'extra_context': {
    'pro': Product.objects.all(),}}),
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Kindly Give your suggestions.

I have searching it for one month.